# Blend colors evenly (dissolve-like) in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, color

Is it possible to blend 2 pictures using similar technique like dissolve but more precisely? I need to mix sources evenly - 1 pixel from the top layer second pixel from bottom layer etc. I work with non liquid products that imitate hair colours (black, dark brown, meduium brown etc)and I would like to show customers what would be the result like if 2 colors are mixed together. In my opinion mixing images dissolve like, would be the best for non liquid sources. Or anybody has better ideas? Thank you

Comment: Set alpha of top layer to 50%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a later mask with a pattern fill based on a 2x2 pixel black and white pattern (created with the pencil tool, not the brush). You can then use a mask on a layer group to paint out any areas you don't want blended.

You can also create a number of different dither patterns to simulate blending in different proportions, either by increasing the size and relative numbers of white and black pixels in the patterrn or by using grey pixels in addition to the black and white.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop has a "dissolve" blending mode.  It blends at the single pixel level, however it randomly picks which later each pixel will come from, so it won't be alternating every other one like you describe.  But I would think it would be more natural to have some randomness thrown in.  If your images are relatively high resolution you won't be able to tell the difference.  Or you can always do a small radius blur to blend them further.